# Is http:// considered as a URI with scheme http and an empty path?

Tags: http, uri

Is **http://** considered as a URI with an empty path? So that **http** is the scheme and **//** is a path value (with an empty path), so that it would be a valid URI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [RFC 3986, section 3](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-3):

> The scheme and path components are required, though the path may be
> empty (no characters)

Hope that answers your question.

([found here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3258977/9690677))